# Volley logs are not fully disable in release build

Tags: android, android-volley, android-logcat

Volley still prints logs in logcat it not disabled . i tried by using proguard-rules.pro but it still shows logs.
here below i add proguard-rules.pro file.

```
-dontwarn **
-target 1.7
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable
-keep class **
-keepclassmembers class *{*;}
-keepattributes *
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
   public static int e(...);
}
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream {
     public void println(%);
     public void println(**);
}
```

it prints something like below in logcat

```
I/System.out: open:http:...
I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=simplifiedcoding.16mb.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=simplifiedcoding.16mb.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
D/FrameworkListener: dispatchCommand data = (getaddrinfo simplifiedcoding.16mb.com ^ 1024 0 1 0 0)
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=simplifiedcoding.16mb.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=local, netid=109; mark=917613
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd: default dns: query_ipv6=1, query_ipv4=1
D/libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = simplifiedcoding.16mb.com, class = 1, type = 28
D/libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = simplifiedcoding.16mb.com, class = 1, type = 1
D/libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = simplifiedcoding.16mb.com succeed
D/SocketClient: SocketClient sendData done: 222
D/SocketClient: SocketClient sendData done: 
D/SocketClient: SocketClient sendData done:
```

suggest me if you have any good solutions

Answer (score 0):

did you mention this in your gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
    }
}
```

if you have set this by default

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

add in this file only

Comment: did made signed apk and installed in your device and checked

Comment: as for my knowledge it does shows logs in android studio for debugging purpose and others it wont show like there some apps to get logs for apps and that time your app don't post logs

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `VolleyLog.DEBUG` in release and debug mode. And try setting `VolleyLog.DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG`. `BuildConfig` class is of your main application package.

Comment: You just need to set VolleyLog.DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG form your main class where you init Volley if using Singleton pattern.

Comment: it display default VolleyLog.DEBUG  = true so i set VolleyLog.DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG like this now i testing it

Comment: What if set to false as a default value always?

Comment: Default value is always true and in Build.Config.DEBUG it also display true

Comment: It should not be the case. BuildConfig.DEBUG in release mode should print false. SInce I am using the same in my applications.

Comment: I know that it print false. I also set as per your instructions but it still shows URL and other information like above.